# Using literal string in Informix queries

Tags: sql, informix

```
select 'literal text' as test_literal_column
from test_table;
```

The above query works in Oracle database. How to write an equivalent query in Informix?

Comment: What doesn't work in Informix?

Comment: That works for me.  Which version of Informix are you using, and/or which interface tool (API?) are you using to send the query to Informix?  AFAICR, that would work in any version of Informix released since 1990.  The type returned is CHAR(12).   You can coerce that to a different type if need be.